# python: conditional statement with else statement in loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

How would I be able to make this if statement more efficient?

```
        if ',' in my_string:
            my_string = my_string.split(',', 1)[0]
            return ', '
        elif '.' in my_string:
            my_string = my_string.split('.', 1)[0]
            return '. '
        elif '?' in my_string:
            my_string = my_string.split('?', 1)[0]
            return '? '
        elif '!' in my_string:
            my_string = my_string.split('!', 1)[0]
            return '! '
        elif ';' in my_string:
            my_string = my_string.split(';', 1)[0]
            return '; '
        else:    
            self.qstring = my_string
            return None
```

I could make a list like:

```
my_list = [',', '.', '?', '!', ';']
```

and loop through, but I'm not sure how to still use the else statement if I put it all in a loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: Presumably `my_string` is preserved somewhere? As your code stands, there is no point in assigning to `my_string`, or even splitting the text, as you return immediately after the split and are thus discarding `my_string`.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the list you have:

```
for delim in my_list:
    if delim in my_string:
        my_string = my_string.split(delim, 1)[0]
        return delim + ' '

self.qstring = my_string
return None
```

Because the loop will `return` the part *after* the loop is not executed if any delimiter matched.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re`:

```
import re

(mystring, delim) = re.split(r'([,\.\?;] )', mystring, 1)[:2]
return delim
```

Comment: I like the `re` approach, but it looks like OP wants to preserve the match and return it.

Comment: Do `.` and `?` need to be escaped inside a character class?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the assignments to `my_string`. Since this is a local variable, this achieves nothing because the value is never returned.